# fopen failed with my file path

Tags: c, fopen

Trying to open and write to the following file path, for some reason it is not opening, I've tried several different paths and nothing has worked. I am running this from C:\

```
FILE* fptwo = fopen("\\C:\\Program Files\\NotMal.txt", "w");
if (fptwo != NULL)
{
    printf("open progfiles successful \n"); 
    //add this text to the file 
    fprintf(fptwo, "This is text");
    printf("add text succuessful \n");

    //close file pointer when finished
    fclose(fptwo);
}
```

*please feel free to delete or close this question if it is answered somewhere else, I apologize for the mistakes made within this, and if it is a stupid error.

Comment: also tried with fopen("C:\\Program Files\\NotMal.txt", "w");

Comment: You probably are not allowed to write to "C:\Program Files", are you?

Comment: You probably have to run your executable as an administrator, because you are writing to a restricted access location.

Comment: @AlexQuilliam I run from Admin each time

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I have the admin rights needed to write to program files

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. If you want to add your own answer, do so in the answer section below.

Answer (score 1):

You test if you have correctly opened the file, it's good !
But it's better to know why your function call have failed.

For "fopen", you can know by looking the value of errno. (read the man about fopen).
And a "cool thing" is that you can obtain an english description by using "strerror".

So, just do :

```
#include <string.h> // For strerror
#include <errno.h> // For .... errno

FILE* fptwo = fopen("\\C:\\Program Files\\NotMal.txt", "w");
if (fptwo == NULL)
{
    printf("Error : errno='%s'.\n", strerror(errno));
}
else
{
    printf("open progfiles successful \n"); 
    //add this text to the file 
    fprintf(fptwo, "This is text");
    printf("add text succuessful \n");

    //close file pointer when finished
    fclose(fptwo);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, added this in now and I can see that the problem is an 'invalid argument', after taking off the leading slashes at the start of the path it works successfully

Comment: If I was to repeat this with the downloads folder, do you know what file path I would need to use? I have tried to use "Downloads\\DownloadedFromInternet.txt" but it says that the file does not exist

Comment: On windows, open a windows explorer on the folder desired, then click the "icon folder" located on the upper part of the windows (like it's an url in a web browser). It will normally expand into the absolute path of the current folder. It's a little hard to explain, did you succeed ?

Answer (score 0):

`Program Files` is windows default software deployment folder. Better not to use that path. Better create your own test folder and test. If possible not to name folder with space.

```
FILE* fptwo = fopen("C:\\MyProject\\test\\NotMal.txt", "w");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback! I also have a function which does write to this folder, but I also intentionally need to write to windows software folder :)